# Name the movie on Nanobots and cheating wife

Tags: identify-this-movie

There was a movie on with the following extracts of the plot.

- There is a blonde person (husband) with his wife
- Wife is in a romantic relationship with some person who has access to latest spy technology
- One day when the husband is about to leave the home, wife applies hair gel on husbands hair, which has nanobots what can be used to track the husband
- Once the husband is out, wife lover uses those nanobots to track down the husband and to kill him
- At the murder attempt, husbands car is knocked over by a large forthcoming truck, where the husbands car is thrown off of a ledge.
- Even though husband's car took a deep dive off of that ledge, he survives the crash.
- Then the husband understands that he is being tracked because of the nanobots his wife applied in his hair, he shaves off his entire hair with a piece of shattered glass of the accident.
- Then the revenge plan begins.

This is an English movie. I do not have any idea of the title, year or any other information.

Does the above ring any bells? Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Hodejegerne (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1614989/)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headhunters_(film))

> Waking in a hospital, Roger learns the police think he is Ove, who arrest him for the farmer's murder when he tries to escape. Driving to the station, the officers pull over to block a truck reported stolen. Remembering that Clas developed a nanotechnology gel that is very difficult to remove, Roger realizes that he's being tracked through GPS gel rubbed in his hair by Diana, and Clas is driving the truck; despite Roger's protests, the officers ignore him, allowing Clas to ram the car off a cliff. Playing dead until Clas leaves the scene, Roger shaves his head and hides his hair on a body, then swaps clothes with a detective's disfigured body to fake his death.